# Standard techniques for forecasting revenue growth of a company?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, econometrics

I was curious what sort of time series models were the standard for doing this type of analysis. I have weekly sales data for the company - I could cook up my own time series model but would like to know what my options are.

Comment: How far into the future are you planning on forecasting? It's hard to say much without knowing this.

Comment: Lets say, a year into the future? It is pretty open ended, I wouldn't want to go too far into the future just because I would like it to remain relatively accurate.

Comment: What's your goal for accuracy?

Comment: I don't know how I would put a number on that - what would that entail?

Comment: Well, to be cynical but honest, your forecasts need to be good enough that you don't fall out of favor with the powers that be. I really am being honest here, basing my response on about five years of doing corporate level forecasting.

Comment: Ok. Let's say my goal is to be as accurate as I can be. For now let's just say least squares to minimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew,

For weekly data, we create 51 dummy variables with a trend and do some stepdown and stepup adjustments to this model.

If you have any impact due to holidays then weekly data is a problem.  If so, move to daily data which is tougher to model but provides a much more robust forecast IF you can do it well.

The stepdown might removed the trend or some or all of the 51 dummies.

Our stepup might include adding dummy variables for outliers, changes in trend/level/seasonality/parameters/variance.

The key to all of this is to think about what truly drives your business and then include those variables as a causal variable and their forecast which will guide the forecast.